# sending message more 70 characters

Tags: android, sms

I have problem with sending message more 70 characters.
On emulator sent is ok, on real phone do not get messages.

example sending message:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{                     
    Log.i(TAG,"sendSMS");
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);  
}
```

what  may be problem?

---

Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try this:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{                     
    Log.i(TAG,"sendSMS");
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> messageParts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    for(String part : messageParts)
    {
       sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, part, null, null);
    }
}
```

Hope, it's help.

Edit 1: look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981430/sending-long-sms-messages)

Edit 2: Do you try use method `sendMultipartTextMessage`?

Comment: i tried to use method sendMultipartTextMessage all working) thank