# What is the limited of chars for SmsManager?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm developing some app that send some SMS messages.
My problem is that when I try to send a long text it won't send the message.
I know there is a limit for the number of characters.

I'm using SmsManager:

```
SmsManager SMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
SMS.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message, null, null);
```

So, what is the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be 160, but the API offers sending in multiple parts using sendMultiPartTextMessage().

[Check out this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981430/sending-long-sms-messages)

Edit: 
[Also this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580675/how-to-send-the-sms-more-than-160-character) , both the accepted answer & 2nd best answer are worth looking at.