# How to send MMS in android behind the scene i.e; programmatically?

Tags: android, sms

Hai ,

In my app , am traping sms . and i have to send an image and text ,to whover sent me an sms , saying that i was busy or some thing ? I did my job with sms is fair and good . But when i am sending mms , i cant send it directly from code unlike sms. ? can any one sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914456/android-sdk-mms). The answer seems to be yes and no. Yes you can, but you have to do it via the MMS app, so its not 100% transparent to the user.

Comment: Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");

Comment: Thanks bramp..... but can yu tell me how to do it ? i have done through fallowing way , but its firing another UI to send , but i need to send directly from source with out user input.

Comment: As the previous answer stated, you can't do it without user input, as there is currently no API for it. Instead you have to fire up the MMS app, which of course is not what you want.