# sending audio throught MMS using intent android

Tags: android, mms

I m new in Android. I am trying to send an MMS with audio file, with m4a format (or other, like AMR, or 3GP). To do this I use an intent but it never sends my MMS. Here isfolowing code I am using:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/m4a");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + new Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/recordaudio.m4a")));
startActivity(share);
```

And my audio flie does not reach more than 30kb.
Could you help me please ?
Sorry for the english I'm French

```
File audiofile = new File(directory,"/recordaudio.m4a");                                        
byte     fileContent[] = new byte[(int) audiofile.length()];                                            
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(audiofile);    

int data = input.read();                                        
while(data != -1) {                                           
    data = input.read(fileContent);                                     
}
input.close();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, mPhoneNumber);
sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileContent);
startActivity(sendIntent);*
```

First of all , thank you very much for your help !!!!
I tried this code and mms is not send...
Could you help me again ??

Comment: This may help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1914522/265167

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1):

What you are sending is the Uri of the audio file but not the audio file itself.

Its not a good idea to send the audio file in the intent

If you still want to send put the byte[] of the audio file in the intent -- after downloading these bytes from the given URI using InputStream

Comment: This will only pass the file bytes to the next activity and not send the mms.