# sendDataMessage() returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, image, sms, mms, sendmessage

I have a problem and Google couldn't help me :-(

I have the requirement to read an image from disk and send it through MMS.
So my code goes like this:

```
in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/phn/Images/D.jpg");
buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
buf.read(bMapArray);                
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);//to display the image on UI
```

Now I am able to see the image which I just converted into bytes. The following code:

```
sms.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber, null, port, bMapArray, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

throws an exception saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
```

Why is `sendDataMessage` unable to read the array of bytes `bMapArray`? Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SmsManager.sendDataMessage()` does not send MMS messages. By means of it you can send SMS message specifying raw data. NullPointerException you get might be related with http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3718 (data you pass it too long)

Try this:
[Android SDK MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914456/android-sdk-mms)