# sending MMS in android programmatically

Tags: android, messaging, mms

Can any one help me with sending MMS programmatically in android, since I am new to developing, I am having trouble understanding this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)!. If anyone could give me a working example that would be great. I've spent a couple of weeks at it now and can;t figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914456/android-sdk-mms

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 0):

there is no public API for handling MMS in android. There are some workarounds, but it may not work on some devices.

Comment: First of all thank you for getting back to me. would you be able to give me an example of one of these workarounds. I've also tried this one [here](http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html) but it doesnt seem to work for me as well. That would be great if you could. i really want to getting it working for a final year project in college.

Comment: I've used this code in my project, last year and it should be working

Comment: When i set the nokia mms it just goes to the main activity and doenst actually send anything. cant figure why it doesnt work. do you think its got something to do with the device?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

you need more clarification go to this link http://jtribe.blogspot.in/2008/12/sending-mms-with-android.html

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say, i want it to send behind the scenes. Is there a  way of picking the chooser option programmtically and sending it without actually physically doing it?