# Sending MMS through Intents in android to a particular number

Tags: android

I have code to send MMS through intents.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

                if(filename != "")
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/"+filename+".jpg"));
                sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

but how come I can send MMS to a particular phone number.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: the code is working, ok. What does it achieve exactly? what does NOT achieve and you'd like to get instead?

Comment: @STTLCU I have written clearly I need to send MMS to a particular phone number.

Comment: you said that this code works. what it does exactly? if it works i understand that you're able to do what you wanted: to send an MMS. otherwise the code is NOT WORKING because you can't send MMS. pick one.

Comment: I cant send MMS directly but rather the user has to choose the application and then enter the phone number, but I want the code directly to send the MMS to a particular number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android SDK MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914456/android-sdk-mms)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked in another thread.
[Android SDK MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914456/android-sdk-mms)

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to perform your requirement.
The nearest you can get is [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) class which send sms behind the scene.